# Transparent activity crashes the app

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a transparent activity so I give the activity the following style:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

I don't know why but it crashes the app.

Any idea why?

EDIT: this is my logcat, i'm a newbie so I don't know much about debugging it.

```
05-14 06:25:08.919    1218-1307/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.myapp.enterprise/.GreenViewActivity} from uid 10057 on display 0
05-14 06:25:08.924    1218-1265/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-14 06:25:08.959    6744-6744/com.myapp.enterprise D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-14 06:25:08.959    6744-6744/com.myapp.enterprise E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.enterprise, PID: 6744
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.enterprise/com.myapp.enterprise.GreenViewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.myapp.enterprise.GreenViewActivity.onCreate(GreenViewActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-14 06:25:08.965    1218-7949/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.myapp.enterprise/.GreenViewActivity
05-14 06:25:08.978    1218-7949/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 2 com.myapp.enterprise/.NoteActivity
05-14 06:25:09.083    1218-2572/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-14 06:25:09.110    1218-2572/system_process W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-14 06:25:09.110    1218-2572/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9d932880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-14 06:25:09.490    1218-1236/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{5ebb3cd u0 com.myapp.enterprise/.GreenViewActivity t546 f}
```

Comment: share your logcat trace

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: try to extend your transparent activity from Activity Instade of ActionBarActivity & put Support v4 jar in lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require to use `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` as parent instead of current `parent="android:Theme"`

Comment: Ok, I tried to remove the theme attribute from the application part of the manifest and put a theme inside of every activity... Didn't work

Comment: What i meant was to change parent in styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

just Use this theme in your activity in Menifest xml file to create Transparent Activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Updated, please check

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending your activity from AppCompactActivity or ActionBarActivity the you must your parent theme

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent"        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

for whole application or for just activty